# Indexed sets - example. How to solve

Tags: set-theory

In my list of exam questions is one to solve an example using indexed sets. I don't really know how to solve this type of examples, because I've never seen this. Also Google gives me just tutorial for unions and intersections, but what about difference and sym. difference?

Here is my example from exams:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czQcm.png)

$\def\Symdiff{\mathop{\lower.48ex\Large\Delta}} \left( \Symdiff\limits_{i}{A_i} \setminus \Symdiff\limits_{i \mathrm{~odd}}{A_i} \right) \vartriangle \bigcup\limits_{i \mathrm{~odd}}{A_i}\text{ }=\text{ } \left( \bigcup\limits_{i \mathrm{~even}}{A_i} \cap \Symdiff\limits_{i \mathrm{~odd}}{A_i} \right) \setminus \Symdiff\limits_{i \mathrm{~even}}{A_i}$

I would like to know this, because I don't wanna fail class.

Comment: hint: $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$;$A\triangle B=A\setminus B \cup B\setminus A$

Comment: Please add the example to your question instead of linking to it. Preferrably using MathJax.

Comment: @JulioMaldonadoHenríquez I know these formulas, but I am not sure if it is working in this case. When I tried to draw Venns' diagrams it didn't work very well. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're not supposed to add the image anyway, as it only contains a formula; you should *type* the formula. Note that you can write formulas by enclosing them in `$` signs and get $\underset{i}\triangle$ using `\underset{i}\triangle` and $\setminus$ with `\setminus`.

Comment: @celtschk didn't know that, thanks. I added the example as a formula.

Comment: @Samuel Illo what do you mean with \Large$_i\Delta$

Comment: maybe $\underset{i}{\Large{\Delta}}$?? this is `$\underset{i}{\Large{\Delta}}$`

Comment: Ask the teacher/instructor/lecturer/professor directly. ASAP.

Comment: This appears to be false in general. Let $A_0$ and $A_1$ be disjoint non-empty sets, and let $A_i=\varnothing$ for $i>1$. Then the lefthand side is $\big((A_0\cup A_1)\setminus A_1\big)\mathop{\triangle}A_1=A_0\mathop{\triangle}A_1=A_0\cup A_1$, but the righthand side is $(A_0\cap A_1)\setminus A_0=\varnothing$.